# Issues where the UI with a specific shader is not visible only on iPhone 14

Tags: shader

I placed the UI with a specific shader in the empty project canvas. But the problem here is that when you build this project, the UI that you can see well on other Android and iOS is not visible only on iPhone 14. If you just apply shader, this problem occurs, so I tried googling and tried many times, but the problem is not fixed. Is this a shader problem? Or is it a problem with iPhone 14?

I tried to add the stencil property from Unity5, but it didn't solve the problem.